# iPhoneと自作VPNサーバとの通信が遅い

Tags: vpn

現在、OpenVPNを使ってVPNサーバを自作しており、iPhoneで通信を取りました。
しかし、通信の速度８bpsという驚異的な遅さで、どのようにKbpsもしくはMbpsくらいのスピードにすればいいのかわからないので、教えていただけると幸いです。

### 開発環境

AWS EC2 t2.micro
OS : Ubuntu 16.04

### 設定ファイル

`server.conf`

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert myservername.crt
key myservername.key
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log         openvpn.log
log-append  openvpn.log
verb 9
auth SHA256
```

`client.ovpn`

```
tls-client
key-direction 1
remote 3.112.20.121
cipher AES-256-CBC
port 1194
proto udp
verb 9
auth SHA256
<ca>
-- Copy of ca.crt --
</ca>
<cert>
-- Copy of client1.crt --
</cert>
<key>
-- Copy of client1.key --
</key>
<tls-auth>
-- Copy of ta.key --
</tls-auth>
```

Comment: iPhone以外の環境では正常に（高速に）VPN接続出来ますか？また、iPhoneでスピードテストを行うとどうなりますか？

Comment: @PicoSushi
コメントありがとうございます。
Macで接続を試みたところ、接続確認はできましたが、macのipaddressは変わらないという不思議な現象になってますね、、、
おそらく正常には接続できていないとおもっているのですが、サーバでもクライアントでもログにエラーが吐かれずに修正の方法もわからない感じですね

Comment: ご質問の内容だとVPNの問題か、iPhoneの問題かを まずは 切り分けたほうが良いと思いました。VPNに繋がない状態の iPhoneはどのくらいの速度が出るかわかりますか？